# Efficiently storing & querying integer arrays in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, set, sql-like

I have a hybrid Cordova Android mobile app which records user activity in a SQLite database.  Each row entry has columns that help characterize the nature of the activity.  One such column records three sub-activities on different days of the week which I represent as an integer array `[0..6,7..13,14..20]` for the three sub-activities.  Further I want to be able to distinguish between activities on "normal" days and days that happen to be public holidays.  I do so by recording a negative entry in the array.  To make this clearer here is an example

```
[0,-2,9,13,-18,20]
```

is representing

- Sub activity A on Sunday
- Sub activity A on public holiday Tuesday
- Sub activity B on Wednesday & Saturday
- Sub activity C on public holiday Friday
- Sub-activity C on Saturday

This is relatively straightforward - I can store the array as JSON.  However, I also want to be able to query this set for membership as efficiently as possible.  The only way I can think of is using a `LIKE` condition. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE activity_column LIKE '%-2%'
```

which I would expect to return all rows where there is recorded activity on public holiday Tuesdays.

I suspect this will probably work.  However, I am a newbie when it comes to Android datbases.  I know that SQLite is the default solution.  Is there an option - either in SQLite or in an alternative - which can render this kind of storage & search more efficient and less convoluted?

Answer (score 0):

This all goes down to how you design your sql base.

One approach would probably be to have 3 tables, one for each activity. The key in each could be the timestamp of the day, and then you could have columns for the json array of your int data.

You can also add an additional quality-of-life column such as "day" where you could keep the int representation of the day of the week.

This way if you wanted data for Activity1 registered on Tuesdays, you would just query

```
SELECT * FROM Activity1 WHERE day = 1
```